# c - WSAWaitForMultipleObjects blocking any thread but last

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winsock

i have a problem with a multi-thread SMTP/POP3 server. The server starts a pool of threads to handle incoming connections. The main thread create the sockets and the the threads, passing the sockets as parameters in a proper structure. The loop function for the threads is the following:

```
SOCKET SMTP_ListenSocket = (SOCKET) data->SMTPconn;
SOCKET POP3_ListenSocket = (SOCKET) data->POP3conn;
static struct sockaddr_in ClntAddr;
unsigned int clntLen = sizeof(ClntAddr);    
hEvents[0] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL); 
hEvents[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
hEvents[2] = exitEvent; //HANDLE FOR A MANUAL RESET EVENT
WSAEventSelect(SMTP_ListenSocket, hEvents[0], FD_ACCEPT); 
WSAEventSelect(POP3_ListenSocket, hEvents[1], FD_ACCEPT); 

while(1){

      DWORD res = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);
      switch(res){

            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: {      
                ClientSocket = my_accept(SMTP_ListenSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr,&clntLen);
                /*  ...  */                    
                my_shutdown(ClientSocket,2);
                my_closesocket(ClientSocket);
                ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        break;
             }

             case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: {

                  ClientSocket = my_accept(POP3_ListenSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr,&clntLen);
                  /* ... */                        
                  my_shutdown(ClientSocket,2);
                  my_closesocket(ClientSocket);
                  ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                  break;
             }

             case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
             {
                  exitHandler(0);
                  break;
             } 
      }//end switch

 }//end while
```

When the pool contains only one thread there's no problem. When the pool consist of more threads, only one thread accepts the incoming connections

Comment: Not an answer as such, but have you considered using IO completion ports? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the pooled threads all calling this same code?  If so, then don't use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` (or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`) like this.  This kind of model only works reliably if one thread is polling connections.  If you have multiple threads polling at the same time, then you have race conditions.

Instead, you should use `AcceptEx()` with Overlapped I/O or Completion Ports instead.  The thread that creates the sockets can call `AcceptEx()` on each socket to queue a new operation on each one, then the pooled threads can use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` or `GetOverlappedResult()` to dequeue a pending connection without worrying about trampling on other threads.  Once a connection is accepted, the receiving thread can process it as needed and then call `AcceptEx()` to queue a new operation for that socket.

Comment: Ok, but the main thread (which creates the sockets) can't wait for incoming connection. The AcceptEx function blocks the main thread and this is not the desired behavior. It must create the sockets, than the thread pool and wait for console events. Only the threads in the pool have to wait for incoming connections.
Have you got some links to io-completion tutorial? I didn't find anything useful yet

Comment: `AcceptEx()` does NOT block the calling thread if you use Overlapped I/O or Completion Ports for the sockets.  Completion Ports scale better, so you should use that if you need to accept a lot of connections.  Look at `CreateIoCompletionPort()` and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread here is setting a new `WSAEventSelect` *prior* to entering the wait. This overwrites any existing event selects. This means that, once a thread (call it thread A) accepts a connection, there is no event associated with the socket.

To solve this, you should call `WSAEventSelect` again within your switch, immediately after the `accept()`. This will restore the event binding immediately before going into any potentially lengthy processing.

Note that it's possible that two threads may be awoken for the same event, if the timing works out just right. You can hack around that by going back to your wait loop if the accept fails, but this is a bit unsatisfying.

So, instead of rolling your own version, use [IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here. I/O completion ports have a number of additional features, and avoid potential race conditions in which two threads might pick up the same event. They also take steps to reduce context switches when your code is not CPU bound.

Comment: calling WSAEventSelect didn't solve the problem. Can you give me some hints to IO completion? Tutorials, code samples